# MS Access error "Operation must use an updatable query" on Update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ms-access

I'm migratting a MS Access system into a mySQL system with PHP PDO. Everything's ok until PHP stop readding some records on an Access table. This table has an ID field that's a Long Integer datatype. I don't know why but the ID starts from 0 to 16949 then jumps to 36573745 and ends at 36581986. These higher numbers the PDO doesn't read, I can't figure out why.

Anyway to workaround this, I'm trying to UPDATE these higher numbers to continue the normal sequence of the lower ID's. But Access can't understand my query and I don't know how to make it run.

This is the query

```
UPDATE Validador_Manut SET ID = (
    SELECT (Max(ID) + 1) FROM Validador_Manut WHERE ID < 100000
) WHERE ID > 100000
```

It's shows me this error `Uperation must use an updatable query`.

Comment: PDO is probably rounding your bigger numbers down to an INT value. You might look at [PDO's bind param](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) since you are already trying PDO. (Even though that query doesn't look like a prepared statement)

Comment: @chapman84 I think PDO is cheating me.

Comment: You could try binding that param as a string instead of an integer and see if your query works. That might tell you if that is what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to lower the IDs > 100000 to consecutive numbers after 16949 
then why don't you try simply this?

```
UPDATE Validador_Manut SET [ID] = [ID]-36556795 WHERE ID > 100000
```

36573745 - 36556795 = 16950

Comment: It throws this error: "Cannot update 'ID'; field not updateable." =S

Comment: That means the ID field is Autonumber and cannot be changed! There isn't a simple way to reset that number. Look at this article on [MSDN support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812718). Reading better your question, perhaps you could simply remove the autonumber flag (with access interface) and then retry the query above

Comment: Yes, just tried on a spare db. If ID is an Autonumber field the query above doesn't work. However, because you are migrating this db into mySql, yuo could change the Autonumber in a normal numeric value and then the query above will work

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to my mind.

**1.) Reserved keywords**

If you use certain keywords as table names or column names, you might get cryptic exception that do not really tell you the actual cause.

Your column `ID` looks suspicious to me.

A short internet search did not bring up an evidence for this theory, but I believe to remember that I saw ID as a reserved word in MS Access somewhere. You could try to

- rename the column
- write column names in angle brackets `[]` *(not recommended)*

**2.)  This article** looks like it could help: [Solving the Operation Must Use An Updateable Query error](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/74/Solving-the-Operation-Must-Use-An-Updateable-Query-error)

> When a Jet 4.0 database (the actual type of database represented by your "Access" mdb file) is deployed in a multi-user environment, an
>   .ldb file is created whenever the database is opened. The .ldb file
>   contains details which include who has opened the file, and primarily
>   serves to prevent opened records being written to by another user.
>
> In the context of an ASP.NET application, who the "user" is will depend on the platform: for XP Pro machines, the user is the ASPNET
>   account. On Windows Server 2003, 2008 and Vista, it is the NETWORK
>   SERVICE account. However, if you have ASP.NET Impersonation enabled,
>   the default user account will be IUSR_machinename, or whichever
>   account you have applied. If you are unsure which account your ASP.NET
>   application is running under, Environment.UserName will return it. To
>   be able to create, write to and delete the required .ldb file, the
>   relevant user needs MODIFY permissions on the folder that the .mdb
>   file is in.
>
> To set this permission, right click on the App_Data folder (or whichever other folder you have put the mdb file in) and select
>   Properties. Look for the Security tab. If you can't see it, you need
>   to go to My Computer, then click Tools and choose Folder Options....
>   then click the View tab. Scroll to the bottom and uncheck "Use simple
>   file sharing (recommended)". Back to the Security tab, you need to add
>   the relevant account to the Group or User Names box. Click Add....
>   then click Advanced, then Find Now. The appropriate account should be
>   listed. Double click it to add it to the Group or User Names box, then
>   check the Modify option in the permissions. That's it. You are done.
>
> Note: this fix will also solve "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file '(unknown)'. It is already opened exclusively by
>   another user, or you need permission to view its data" errors.

Comment: Nope man, the second suggestion doesn't worked, or I done it wrong, I don'k now. The first I think not, cause I can use `ID` field to simple updates, inserts or selects, you know..